# Sub group aggregation with Case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to return the list of groupid's, masteraccountnames and CashAmountDiff where the sum of the CashAmount of the trades with the same groupid is great than 100 for any date.

The table schemas are like so:

**TradeT1**

```
TradeId | SubAccountId | MasterAccId | GroupId | TradeDate | TradeType
```

**MasterAccount**

```
Id | MasterAccName
```

**SubAccount**

```
Id | SubAccName | MasterAccountId
```

Each SubAccount is linked to a MasterAccount. It is a Many-to-one relationship.

TradeType determines the 'direction' of the trade, whether it's debit or credit. I am having trouble adding the debits and credits per groupid. My query is just summing everything. I'm not sure how to incorporate the Case When Credit (multiply CashAmount * -1), Case When Debit just use CashAmount

There will always be more than 1 tradeid linked to a single groupid.

I have the tables in SQL fiddle here along with my effort: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45580/1/0

```
SELECT 
t.groupId,
ma.MasterAccName,
sum(CASE WHEN t.tradetype = 'Credit' 
       THEN sum(-1*t.cashamount)
    ELSE sum(t.cashamount)) 
END as CashDiff 
FROM tradet1 t
JOIN masteraccount ma
ON t.masteraccid = ma.id 
WHERE t.groupid > -1
GROUP BY t.groupid, ma.MasterAccName
HAVING count(t.groupid) > 1 and sum(t.cashamount) > 100
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: No CashAmount or CashAmountDiff columns defined

Comment: Code updated but not compiling. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45580/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this query quite a bit by converting your credits and debits in a sub-query and using those results in your aggregate query.

Such as

```
SELECT    [tt].[GroupId] ,
          [ma].[MasterAccName] ,
          CASE WHEN [tt].[TradeType] = 'Credit'
               THEN [tt].[CashAmount] * -1
               ELSE [tt].[CashAmount]
               END AS CashAmount
FROM      [dbo].[TradeT1] AS tt
          JOIN [dbo].[MasterAccount] AS ma ON [tt].[MasterAccId] = [ma].[Id]
```

With this, you have a nice list of CashAmounts as positive and negative to use in a surrounding aggregate query.

The whole query would look like this

```
SELECT  [tn].[GroupId] ,
        [tn].[MasterAccName] ,
        SUM([tn].[CashAmount]) AS CashDiff
FROM    ( SELECT    [tt].[GroupId] ,
                    [ma].[MasterAccName] ,
                    CASE WHEN [tt].[TradeType] = 'Credit'
                         THEN [tt].[CashAmount] * -1
                         ELSE [tt].[CashAmount]
                    END AS CashAmount
          FROM      [dbo].[TradeT1] AS tt
                    JOIN [dbo].[MasterAccount] AS ma ON [tt].[MasterAccId] = [ma].[Id]
        ) AS tn
GROUP BY [tn].[GroupId] ,
        [tn].[MasterAccName]
HAVING  ABS(SUM([tn].[CashAmount])) > 100 AND COUNT([tn].[GroupId]) > 1
```

Comment: THanks Ken. Identical results. This is quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This is just your query adapted for +/-. I might have the signs backkwards.

```
Select 
  t.groupId,
  ma.MasterAccName,
  Sum (Case When TradeType = 'Credit' Then -t.cashamount Else t.cashamount End) AS 'CashDiff'
From 
  tradet1 t
      Inner Join
  masteraccount ma
      On t.masteraccid = ma.id 
 Where
  t.groupid > -1
 Group By
  t.groupid,
  ma.MasterAccName
Having
  Count(t.groupid) > 1 And
  Sum (Case When TradeType = 'Credit' Then -t.cashamount Else t.cashamount End) > 100
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45580/20

Comment: Your query misses groupid 8888. I believe I may have the answer here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/886c7/4/0

Comment: The fiddle I linked to had the signs backwards. You need to be clearer about what you want when you say the sum is greater than 100. Is that the sum with debits as pluses and credits as minuses?

Comment: Yes, debits as pluses and credits as minuses and to be absolutely clear (greater than 100 or less than -100 - the absolute value of the CashDiff) Actually my fiddle is still incorrect. The aggregate figure returned in the CashDiff is incorrect. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bfea/4

Comment: Laurence, thanks for your help. A slight modification of your code appears to work perfectly well. Appreciate it.